# Current List view in SharePoint 2013 custom action

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to create a custom list action for SharePoint (Office 365) and I need to get current list view. However if I add ribbon action I have some problems to find currently selected list view. My trials:

a) It would be the best to have some url tokent (like {View}) with current view ID, however it looks like such does not exist.

b) I had an idea to find selected view from the source url, however if I add Source={Source} parameter to the custom action, I get Source resolved to : Source=https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/commandui.ashx?ver=%2D1037522208&lcid=1033&qt=commandhandlers 
(while I'd expect something like https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/My%20List/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence )

c) .. ?

Any ideas how to get currently selected list view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it looks like there are more then one way to create custom action for every list. My way was just remove RegistrationType and RegistrationId:

```
<CustomAction 
      Id="65695319-4784-478e-8dcd-4e541cb1d682.CustomAction"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
      Sequence="10001"
      Title="Invoke custom action">
```

Another way is to register custom action to content to content type 0x01:

```
<CustomAction 
       Id="65695319-4784-478e-8dcd-4e541cb1d682.CustomAction" 
       Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"    
       RegistrationType="ContentType"
       RegistrationId="0x01"
       Sequence="10001" 
       Title="Invoke custom action">
```

This way I get results as expected

Comment: How does this answer you question? I'm having the same question as you had and this answer don't help me a bit. Someone just wanted to answer themself to get some points or what? How do you get the currently selected view id?

Comment: No problem. I am not angry on you